# breakdown on a PHP program that will get the average, highest, lowest score based from the 5 scores

Tags: php

I am still unfamiliar with PHP but I was tasked to do the following

> Create a program in PHP that will get the average, highest, lowest score based from the 5 scores from the team. Given teamscore = {85,70,90,95,88}. Your program must have the corresponding functions: displayScores(), getAverageScore(), getHighestScore(), getLowestScore(). Hint: for displayScores(), you should make them as string to display all scores.
> I would like to see the code and the breakdown on how it functions so I could understand it a bit more in-depth

I tried using references given to us but i can't understand it that much so I researche don google to find a similar solution however there were none.

Answer (score 0):

we will create a class that has a property `scores` array, and the 4 methods, `getScores`, `getAvarage`, `getHighest` & `getLowest`:

```php
class Scores
{
    private array $scores;

    /**
     * we pass the scores to the constructor and sort them
     * @param array $scores
     */
    public function __construct(array $scores)
    {
        sort($scores); // sort method uses the pointer
        $this->scores = $scores;
    }

    public function getScores(): array
    {
        return $this->scores;
    }

    public function getAvarage(): float
    {
        return array_sum($this->scores) / count($this->scores);
    }

    public function getHighest(): int
    {
        return end($this->scores); // we will return the last element of the array as it's already sorted ascending
    }

    public function getLowest(): ?int
    {
        return $this->scores[0] ?? null; // we will return the first element of the array if it's set, or null if it's not
    }
}
```

here is a simple implementation, please let me know if there is something not clear

edit:
here is how to use it:

```php
$scores = new Scores([85, 70, 90, 95, 88]);

$avarage = $scores->getAvarage();
$highest = $scores->getHighest();
$lowest = $scores->getLowest();
```

Comment: so do I put the $scores on top of the code above or below?

Comment: it doesn't mind if it was above or below